# iOS FCM push notification data payload

Tags: swift

I'm receiving from FCM push notification like following. How do I get data from "data" in AppDelegate

```
    "to": "eTDYm1eJzUA-pRUNQ0pq9S:APA91CLfb1XQbsxUV0VIqTSV6A1YdXbKpRa9XkzZ6Px6Ww0-zQFU9OI0rgag_3Lwlu1yA1hbT-mQO6Ku37qNnuM6bKGfdOfAX-M0",
    "notification":{
        "body":"body",
        "title":"This is title",
        "sound": "default",
        "mutable_content": true
    },
    "data" : {
        "user_name": "user name",

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase sends us Map and we should cast it to [String: Any] and get value from key

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("didReceive response TAPPED TO NOTIFICATION")

        let userName = response.notification.request.content.userInfo["user_name"] as? [String : Any]
        print(userName)
        completionHandler()
    }
```